# Problema Arduino Nano Generico

Tags: arduino

Estoy teniendo problemas con una placa Arduino Nano genérico. Cuando lo conecto a mi computadora (Mac, con sistema operativo Mojave) e intento subir el código de ejemplo, blink, que viene con el programa. Me pone este error :

```
El Sketch usa 444 bytes (1%) del espacio de almacenamiento de programa. El 
máximo es 30720 bytes.
Las variables Globales usan 9 bytes (0%) de la memoria dinámica, dejando 2039 
bytes para las variables locales. El máximo es 2048 bytes.
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
(Pone lo mismo 10 veces)
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
Problema subiendo a la placa. Visita 
http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload para sugerencias.
```

Pensé que el problema eran lo drivers del CH2340G, así que los instale. Aun así me sigue apareciendo ese error

De antemano, Gracias

Comment: tienes bien configurado la conexion al arduino? tiene pinta de que no esta configurado correctamente (seleccionado el arduino correcto, puerto...)

Comment: Sí, cuando no hay ningún Arduino conectado solo me aparece : /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming Port. En cambio cuando conecto el Arduino Nano me aparece /dev/cu.usbserial-1410 (este es el que selecciono cuando intento subir el programa y me pone el error).

Comment: Nunca he programado un Arduino desde Mac, pero una vez me estaba dando el mismo problema y lo que hice para solucionarlo fue ir probando cada velocidad de baudios hasta que funcionara con alguno.